# pandas max function results in inoperable DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with four columns and want to generate a new `DataFrame` with only one column containing the maximum value of each row. 
Using `df2 = df1.max(axis=1)` gave me the correct results, but the column is titled `0` and is not operable. Meaning I can not check it's data type or change it's name, which is critical for further processing. Does anyone know what is going on here? Or better yet, has a better way to generate this new `DataFrame`?

Answer (score 1):

It is `Series`, for one column `DataFrame` use [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df2 = df1.max(axis=1).to_frame('maximum')
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Earlier I changed it to frame and tried to change the name afterwards, but it didn't work